# ref to a const default parameter using other parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, copy-constructor

I am creating a custom forward_list and am having a problem making [this copy constructor.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/forward_list)
The problem is that, in my forward_list I have a private variable `A& heap;`, and I would like to instantiate it with alloc, unless alloc is not provided (which I do not understand how that is a possibility since alloc is a reference parameter and therefore **must** be provided?).
The only place I could therefore instantiate alloc if not somehow provided would be in the init list (since it is a reference), but I can't, because allocator_traits requires other.get_allocator(), which is another parameter.

---

```
template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class forward_list
{
    ...
private:
    struct node
    {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<T> next;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<node> root_;
    std::unique_ptr<node> leaf_;
    size_t count_;
    const A& heap;
}
```

---

```
/* Copy constructor. Constructs the container with the copy of the contents of other.
 * If alloc is not provided, allocator is obtained by calling
 * std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator());
 */
forward_list(const forward_list& other, const A& alloc = A())
 : heap(std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator()))
{
}
```

Comment: Your constructor will not work as a copy constructor unless there is a default value for the second argument.

Comment: Yes, but the real question is, if I am providing a default value, how would I know in the initializer list if this parameter was passed int or... is the default value? Since the only way to initialize a variable ref would be in the initializer list.

Comment: There are many ways to determine that. You can implement a copy constructor that does not have the second argument, and then use [delegating constructor](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor) to re-use common code.

Comment: @RSahu: your link is not formatted correctly.  The last `]` should be a `)` instead, and thus is breaking the URL fragment.

Comment: @R Sahu so you're saying overload the operator the old fashioned way and call one from the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inline forward_list(const forward_list& other)
 : root_(other.root_), leaf_(other.leaf_), count_(other.count_), heap(std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator())) {};

inline forward_list(const forward_list& other, const A& alloc)
 : root_(other.root_), leaf_(other.leaf_), count_(other.count_), heap(alloc) {};
```